# Assign shortcut key for zoom In/ zoom Out buttons for fs.zoomer.js

Tags: jquery, zooming

Please visit to check http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Image-Enlargement-Plugin-Zoomer/

I want to add shortcut keys for zoom In and zoom Out buttons. I tried but not getting proper event listener to start work.

Thanks in advance.

And you will get plugin from here

http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/Smooth-Image-Enlargement-Plugin-Zoomer.html

Comment: How you try? Can you please share your code

Comment: Okay, Just to find main zoom function, I added  extra buttons for zoomIn/out. I found _zoomIn() function inside jquery.fs.zoomer.js and called this function as $(document).on("click",".zoominn",function({console.log("zoom In");
  _zoomIn(); 
  }); I'm guessing, This code is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i have testing in my local machine it's working perfect.

Add Script in header

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".demo .zoomer_basic").zoomer();

            $(".zoominn").click(function () {
                $(".demo .zoomer_basic").zoomer('zoomInn');
            });

            $(".zoomoutt").click(function () {
                $(".demo .zoomer_basic").zoomer('zoomOutt');
            });

            $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
                $(".demo .zoomer_wrapper").zoomer("resize");
            });

            $(window).one("pronto.load", function () {
                $(".demo .zoomer_basic").zoomer("destroy");
                $(".demo .zoomer_custom").zoomer("destroy");
                $(".demo .zoomer_tiled").zoomer("destroy");
                $(".demo .load_zoomer_tiled").off("click");
            });
        });
</script>
```

That's code include in the **pub object** under the **destroy method**

```
/**
     * @method
     * @name zoomInn
     * @example $(".target").zoomer("zoomInn");
     */
    zoomInn: function() {
        var $targets = $(this).each(function(i, target) {
            var data = $(target).data("zoomer");

            if (data) {
                data = _setZoomPosition(data);
                data.keyDownTime = 1;
                data.action = "zoom_in";

                data = _clearZoomPosition(data);
            }

        });

        return $targets;
    },

    /**
     * @method
     * @name zoomOutt
     * @example $(".target").zoomer("zoomOutt");
     */
    zoomOutt: function() {
        var $targets = $(this).each(function(i, target) {
            var data = $(target).data("zoomer");

            if (data) {
                data = _setZoomPosition(data);
                data.keyDownTime = 1;
                data.action = "zoom_out";

                data = _clearZoomPosition(data);
            }

        });

        return $targets;
    },
```

Comment: Imran, I want to use basic version of zoomer only with zoom In and zoomout buttons. first demo is working fine for me. only the problem is I want to call both options using shortcut keys. that is required in the app I'm developing.

Comment: Thnx for your efforts Imran, Now you can check this jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/amitv1093/dLw9knqu/. I did as you said and call in going inside zoomInn as you can see alert is coming. But nothing change on button click. It will be good  for me, if you add your changes on my fiddle and share working example.

Comment: Please accept my ans now if your requirement is fullfill

Comment: Sure bro will do :-) Plz help me in solving this.

Comment: Its working fine bro. problem is zoomIn and zoomOut are happening without interval, means on zoomIn click, image zoom to max and original size on zoomout. Also dragging is not working. can you fix it? I have to deploy this asap. thnx again bro.

Comment: Imran did u check for those two issues?

Comment: I am looking the code, still didn't find the option to zoom not max, the code is work on drag starting

Comment: Cool!! thnx bro :-) me too trying from my end.

Comment: Drag is working now by adding data = _clearZoomPosition(data);

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Your real techie :-). Please provide solution for incremental zooming. Thanks again.